# Is preallocation possible in this code snippet?

Tags: algorithm, matlab

The following is a snippet of code of Ant Colony Optimization. I've removed whatever I feel would absolutely not be necessary to understand the code. The rest I'm not sure as I'm unfamiliar with coding on matlab. However, I'm running this algorithm on 500 or so cities with 500 ants and 1000 iterations, and the code runs extremely slow as compared to other algorithm implementations on matlab. For the purposes of my project, I simply need the datasets, not demonstrate coding capability on matlab, and I had time constraints that simply did not allow me to learn matlab from scratch, as that was not taken into consideration nor expected when the deadline was given, so I got the algorithm from an online source.

Matlab recommends preallocating two variables inside a loop as they are arrays that change size I believe. However I do not fully understand the purpose of those two parts of the code, so I haven't been able to do so. I believe both arrays increment a new item every iteration of the loop, so technically they should both be zero-able and could preallocate the size of both expected final sizes based on the for loop condition, but I'm not sure. I've tried preallocating zeroes to the two arrays, but it does not seem to fix anything as Matlab still shows preallocate for speed recommendation.

I've added two comments on the two variables recommended by MATLAB to preallocate below. If someone would be kind as to skim over it and let me know if it is possible, it'd be much appreciated.

```
    x = 10*rand(50,1);
    y = 10*rand(50,1);
    n=numel(x);
    D=zeros(n,n);

    for i=1:n-1
        for j=i+1:n
            D(i,j)=sqrt((x(i)-x(j))^2+(y(i)-y(j))^2);
            D(j,i)=D(i,j);
        end
    end

    model.n=n;
    model.x=x;
    model.y=y;
    model.D=D;

nVar=model.n;

MaxIt=100;     
nAnt=50;

Q=1;

tau0=10*Q/(nVar*mean(model.D(:)));

alpha=1;
beta=5;
rho=0.6;

eta=1./model.D;
tau=tau0*ones(nVar,nVar);
BestCost=zeros(MaxIt,1);

empty_ant.Tour=[];
empty_ant.Cost=[];

ant=repmat(empty_ant,nAnt,1);

BestSol.Cost=inf;

for it=1:MaxIt

    for k=1:nAnt
        ant(k).Tour=randi([1 nVar]);

        for l=2:nVar
            i=ant(k).Tour(end);
            P=tau(i,:).^alpha.*eta(i,:).^beta;
            P(ant(k).Tour)=0;
            P=P/sum(P);
            r=rand;
            C=cumsum(P);
            j=find(r<=C,1,'first');
            ant(k).Tour=[ant(k).Tour j];
        end

        tour = ant(k).Tour;
        n=numel(tour);
        tour=[tour tour(1)]; %MatLab recommends preallocation here
        ant(k).Cost=0;

        for i=1:n
        ant(k).Cost=ant(k).Cost+model.D(tour(i),tour(i+1));
        end

        if ant(k).Cost<BestSol.Cost
            BestSol=ant(k);
        end

    end

    for k=1:nAnt
        tour=ant(k).Tour;
        tour=[tour tour(1)];

        for l=1:nVar
            i=tour(l);
            j=tour(l+1);
            tau(i,j)=tau(i,j)+Q/ant(k).Cost;
        end

    end

    tau=(1-rho)*tau;

    BestCost(it)=BestSol.Cost;

    figure(1);
    tour=BestSol.Tour;
    tour=[tour tour(1)];  %MatLab recommends preallocation here
    plot(model.x(tour),model.y(tour),'g.-');
end
```

Comment: The matlab warning means that once you know the final size of `tour`, you should preallocate the needed memory before the loop by doing `tour = zeros(final_size);`. Instead of being a changing size array, it becomes a fixed size array all along the script.

Comment: Then instead of `tour=[tour tour(1)];` which expands the size, it should be something like `tour(:,k) = tour(1);`

Comment: I can't check all this in my computer since your code costs too much, please reduce it to focus on the strict essential.

Comment: @Bebs Thanks for the assistance! I've changed the number of ants and iteration count as well as decreased the coordinates plotted. The cost should be lower now! And this is reduced actually, I just didn't know what else to cut down without running the risk of the code not working, sorry.

Comment: @Bebs Yes, I looked up preallocation earlier and found the part about the fixed size array, but `tour(:,k) = tour(1);` I don't quite get what the ':' and 'k' means here. I tried preallocating based on final size (I tried zeros(), but that might still show as numeric values and not be ideal, so perhaps NaN?) but I'm not sure what the final size here was. If you could show one of the tours changed like that, I could try and understand it to implement it on the other one! Or if it's easy, if you could answer with the fixed code snippet and I'll accept it.

Comment: I think that the warning that the MATLAB Editor gives in this case is misplaced. The array is not repeatedly resized, it is just resized once. In principle, `tour(end+1)=tour(1)` is more efficient than `tour=[tour,tour(1)]`, but in this case you might not notice the difference in cost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the size of an array, that means copying it to a new location in memory. This is not a huge problem for small arrays but for large arrays this slows down your code immensely. The tour arrays you're using are fixed size (51 or n+1 in this case) so you should preallocate them as zero arrays. the only thing you do is add the first element of the tour again to the end so all you have to do is set the last element of the array.

Here is what you should change:

```
x = 10*rand(50,1);
y = 10*rand(50,1);
n=numel(x);
D=zeros(n,n);

for i=1:n-1
    for j=i+1:n
        D(i,j)=sqrt((x(i)-x(j))^2+(y(i)-y(j))^2);
        D(j,i)=D(i,j);
    end
end

model.n=n;
model.x=x;
model.y=y;
model.D=D;

nVar=model.n;

MaxIt=1000;     
nAnt=50;

Q=1;

tau0=10*Q/(nVar*mean(model.D(:)));

alpha=1;
beta=5;
rho=0.6;

eta=1./model.D;
tau=tau0*ones(nVar,nVar);
BestCost=zeros(MaxIt,1);

empty_ant.Tour=zeros(n, 1);
empty_ant.Cost=[];

ant=repmat(empty_ant,nAnt,1);

BestSol.Cost=inf;

for it=1:MaxIt

    for k=1:nAnt
        ant(k).Tour=randi([1 nVar]);

        for l=2:nVar
            i=ant(k).Tour(end);
            P=tau(i,:).^alpha.*eta(i,:).^beta;
            P(ant(k).Tour)=0;
            P=P/sum(P);
            r=rand;
            C=cumsum(P);
            j=find(r<=C,1,'first');
            ant(k).Tour=[ant(k).Tour j];
        end
        tour = zeros(n+1,1);
        tour(1:n) = ant(k).Tour;
        n=numel(ant(k).Tour);
        tour(end) = tour(1); %MatLab recommends preallocation here
        ant(k).Cost=0;

        for i=1:n
        ant(k).Cost=ant(k).Cost+model.D(tour(i),tour(i+1));
        end

        if ant(k).Cost<BestSol.Cost
            BestSol=ant(k);
        end

    end

    for k=1:nAnt
        tour(1:n)=ant(k).Tour;
        tour(end) = tour(1);

        for l=1:nVar
            i=tour(l);
            j=tour(l+1);
            tau(i,j)=tau(i,j)+Q/ant(k).Cost;
        end

    end

    tau=(1-rho)*tau;

    BestCost(it)=BestSol.Cost;

    figure(1);
    tour(1:n) = BestSol.Tour;
    tour(end) = tour(1);  %MatLab recommends preallocation here
    plot(model.x(tour),model.y(tour),'g.-');
end
```

Comment: Did you actually time the code? I would be very surprised if this was any faster than the original code, it likely is slower because indexing is more expensive than appending one item.

Comment: No i didn't. and you're indeed right in this case! I guess matlab constantly nagging when i don't preallocate arrays has misled me here

Answer (score 0):

I think that the warning that the MATLAB Editor gives in this case is misplaced. The array is not repeatedly resized, it is just resized once. In principle, `tour(end+1)=tour(1)` is more efficient than `tour=[tour,tour(1)]`, but in this case you might not notice the difference in cost.

If you want to speed up this code you could think of vectorizing some of its loops, and of reducing the number of indexing operations performed. For example this section:

```
tour = ant(k).Tour;
n=numel(tour);
tour=[tour tour(1)]; %MatLab recommends preallocation here
ant(k).Cost=0;

for i=1:n
   ant(k).Cost=ant(k).Cost+model.D(tour(i),tour(i+1));
end

if ant(k).Cost<BestSol.Cost
   BestSol=ant(k);
end
```

could be written as:

```
tour = ant(k).Tour;
ind = sub2ind(size(model.D),tour,circshift(tour,-1));
ant(k).Cost = sum(model.D(ind));
if ant(k).Cost < BestSol.Cost
   BestSol = ant(k);
end
```

This rewritten code doesn't have a loop, which *usually* makes things a little faster, and it also doesn't repeatedly do complicated indexing (`ant(k).Cost` is two indexing operations, within a loop that will slow you down more than necessary).

There are more opportunities for optimization like these, but rewriting the whole function is outside the scope of this answer.

I have not tried running the code, please let me know if there are any errors when using the proposed change.

Comment: I tried it, it tells me `'cost' requires one of the following:
  Audio System Toolbox
  DSP System Toolbox

Error in aco_tsp (line 102)
        if cost < BestSol.Cost` I think possibly because I didn't install any toolboxes?